# Populate dropdownlist using AngularJS, values returned from WCF Rest Service

Tags: angularjs, html, wcf

below is my JSON object **Ctrlr.status** values

```
"[{\"Key\":\"8\",\"Value\":\"Auto\",\"Tid\":\"Date(-62135596800000)\",\"Uid\":null},{\"Key\":\"2\",\"Value\":\"Pending\",\"Tid\":\"Date(-62135596800000)\",\"Uid\":null},{\"Key\":\"4\",\"Value\":\"Resolution\",\"Tid\":\"Date(-62135596800000)\",\"Uid\":null},{\"Key\":\"6\",\"Value\":\"Resolve\",\"Tid\":\"Date(-62135596800000)\",\"Uid\":null}]"
```

my dropdownlist should have values Auto,Pending,Resolution,Resolve.

below is my code display dropdownlist

```
<select ng-model="gridCtrl.add.Rejection.status" ng-required="true"
                            options="s.value for s in Ctrlr.status"/>
```

But it is displaying empty list. Please point out my mistakes and tell me how to populate this values. Thanks in advance

Comment: and ng-Model should keep key with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by assigning your JSON array to a variable on the scope, like so:

```
$scope.statuses = [{\"Key\":\"8\",\"Value\":\"Auto\",\"Tid\":\"Date(-62135596800000)\",\"Uid\":null},{\"Key\":\"2\",\"Value\":\"Pending\",\"Tid\":\"Date(-62135596800000)\",\"Uid\":null},{\"Key\":\"4\",\"Value\":\"Resolution\",\"Tid\":\"Date(-62135596800000)\",\"Uid\":null},{\"Key\":\"6\",\"Value\":\"Resolve\",\"Tid\":\"Date(-62135596800000)\",\"Uid\":null}]
```

then you can loop over it with a

> ng-options

something like

```
ng-options="status.Key as status.Value for status in statuses"
```

See working plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ethtRJbUgTiDCgOG6nJ0?p=preview)